# Play Framework: Error getting sequence nextval using H2 in-memory database

Tags: jdbc, playframework-2.0, h2, ebean

As the title suggests, I get an error running Play 2.0.1 Tests using a FakeApplication w/ H2 in memory.

I set up a basic unit test:

```
public class ModelTest {
    @Test
    public void checkThatIndustriesExist() {
        running(fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase()), new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Industry industry = new Industry();
                industry.name = "Some name";
                industry.shortname = "some-name";
                industry.save();
                assertThat(Industry.find.all()).hasSize(1);
            }
        });
    }
```

Which yields the following exception:

```
[info] test.ModelTest
[error] Test test.ModelTest.checkThatIndustriesExist failed: Error getting sequence nextval
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.SequenceIdGenerator.getMoreIds(SequenceIdGenerator.java:213)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.SequenceIdGenerator.loadMoreIds(SequenceIdGenerator.java:163)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.SequenceIdGenerator.nextId(SequenceIdGenerator.java:118)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptor.nextId(BeanDescriptor.java:1218)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.setIdGenValue(DefaultPersister.java:1304)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.insert(DefaultPersister.java:403)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.saveEnhanced(DefaultPersister.java:345)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.saveRecurse(DefaultPersister.java:315)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.save(DefaultPersister.java:282)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1577)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1567)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.save(Ebean.java:538)
[error]     at play.db.ebean.Model.save(Model.java:76)
[error]     at test.ModelTest$1.run(ModelTest.java:24)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:277)
[error]     at test.ModelTest.checkThatIndustriesExist(ModelTest.java:21)
[error]     ...
[error] Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax Fehler in SQL Befehl "SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION[*] SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL "; erwartet "identifier"
[error] Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION[*] SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
[error] select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval [42001-158]
[error]     at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
[error]     at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
[error]     at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:194)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readColumnIdentifier(Parser.java:2777)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readTermObjectDot(Parser.java:2336)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:2453)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:2035)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:2022)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:1995)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:1860)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readAnd(Parser.java:1841)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:1833)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleSelectPart(Parser.java:1746)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1778)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1673)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1518)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1506)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:405)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:217)
[error]     at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:415)
[error]     at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:364)
[error]     at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1119)
[error]     at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:71)
[error]     at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:267)
[error]     at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.prepareStatement(ConnectionHandle.java:820)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.SequenceIdGenerator.getMoreIds(SequenceIdGenerator.java:193)
[error]     ... 80 more
```

My model looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "industry")
public class Industry extends Model {
    @Id public Long id;
    public String name;
    public String shortname;

    // called in the view to trigger lazy-loading
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static Finder<Long, Industry> find = new Finder<Long, Industry>(Long.class, Industry.class);
}
```

... and finally the relevant part from my initial evolution:

```
create table industry (
    id        bigint not null,
    name      varchar(255),
    shortname varchar(255),
    constraint pk_industry primary key (id)
}

create sequence industry_seq start with 1000;
```

Everything works fine running on my PostgreSQL DB, and from my point of view the code is not any different from the [Play2.0 Computer Database Sample](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java/computer-database).

I am happy for any help - thanks!

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved the problem, here's how:

- before calling inMemoryDatabase() I provided my own config
- the name of the database was 'test' and not 'default' as is used by calling inMemoryDatabase()
- since I did not keep evolutions in conf/evolutions/test but only in conf/evolutions/default the schema hasn't been created
- I had to clean the app, as the 'default' config wasn't applied after the change to inMemoryDatabase()

Comment: I will; need to wait another 23 hours until I'm allowed to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Just using your code and a new Play **2.0.1** project I could not reproduce. Here is my code  and config *with* imports. Since the classes are not the problem my guess would be that you switched off evolutions with `evolutionplugin=disabled` and your database evolution does never get applied, hence the "identifier expected" in your exception.

**Edit** disabling database evolutions, as stated above, yields the same exception that you encountered, see at the bottom.

**Edit-2** the author of [this blogpost](http://blog.matthieuguillermin.fr/2012/03/unit-testing-tricks-for-play-2-0-and-ebean/) describes how to apply the evolutions by hand. Doesn't look too sexy, but I you should only need to implement that base-class once per project. If someone knows something more elegant within the framework, do tell.

The Ebean Evolution (automatically generated):

```
create table industry (   
  id              bigint not null,  
  name            varchar(255),   shortname                
  varchar(255),   constraint pk_industry primary key (id)) ;
  create sequence industry_seq;
;
```

My models.Industry

```java
package models;

import play.db.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "industry")
public class Industry extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public String shortname;

    // called in the view to trigger lazy-loading
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static Finder<Long, Industry> find 
           = new Model.Finder<Long, Industry>(Long.class, Industry.class);
}
```

My Unit-Test

```java
package models;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.assertThat;
import static play.test.Helpers.fakeApplication;
import static play.test.Helpers.inMemoryDatabase;
import static play.test.Helpers.running;

public class ModelTest {

    @Test
    public void checkThatIndustriesExist() {
        running(fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase()), new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Industry industry = new Industry();
                industry.name = "Some name";
                industry.shortname = "some-name";
                industry.save();
                assertThat(Industry.find.all()).hasSize(1);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

My appication.conf

```
application.secret="8aXG0?h`kxccxs6JM?WdB@<v`kwouvQr2<y5Y>9jk3XU1yHV`Yr>18xRKHv8PTdv"
application.langs="en"
ebean.default="models.*"
logger.root=ERROR
logger.play=INFO
logger.application=DEBUG
```

Test output:

```
[stackoverflow-10869508] $ test
[info] Updating {file:/Users/martin/workspace/stackoverflow-10869508/}stackoverflow-10869508...
[info] Done updating.                                                                  
[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 3 Java sources to /Users/martin/workspace/stackoverflow-10869508/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to /Users/martin/workspace/stackoverflow-10869508/target/scala-2.9.1/test-classes...
[info] models.ModelTest
[info] + models.ModelTest.checkThatIndustriesExist
[info] 
[info] 
[info] Total for test models.ModelTest
[info] Finished in 2.289 seconds
[info] 1 tests, 0 failures, 0 errors
[info] Passed: : Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1, Skipped 0
```

Test output disabling evolutions:

```
[stackoverflow-10869508] $ test
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to /Users/martin/workspace/stackoverflow-10869508/target/scala-2.9.1/test-classes...
[info] models.ModelTest
[error] Test models.ModelTest.checkThatIndustriesExist failed: Error getting sequence nextval
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.SequenceIdGenerator.getMoreIds(SequenceIdGenerator.java:213)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.SequenceIdGenerator.loadMoreIds(SequenceIdGenerator.java:163)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.SequenceIdGenerator.nextId(SequenceIdGenerator.java:118)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptor.nextId(BeanDescriptor.java:1218)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.setIdGenValue(DefaultPersister.java:1304)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.insert(DefaultPersister.java:403)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.saveEnhanced(DefaultPersister.java:345)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.saveRecurse(DefaultPersister.java:315)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.save(DefaultPersister.java:282)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1577)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1567)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.save(Ebean.java:538)
[error]     at play.db.ebean.Model.save(Model.java:76)
[error]     at models.ModelTest$1.run(ModelTest.java:22)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:277)
[error]     at models.ModelTest.checkThatIndustriesExist(ModelTest.java:17)
[error]     ...
[error] Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax Fehler in SQL Befehl "SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION[*] SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL "; erwartet "identifier"
[error] Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION[*] SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL UNION SELECT INDUSTRY_SEQ.NEXTVAL "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
[error] select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval union select industry_seq.nextval [42001-158]
[error]     at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
[error]     at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
[error]     at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:194)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readColumnIdentifier(Parser.java:2777)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readTermObjectDot(Parser.java:2336)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:2453)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:2035)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:2022)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:1995)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:1860)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readAnd(Parser.java:1841)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:1833)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleSelectPart(Parser.java:1746)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1778)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1673)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1518)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1506)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:405)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:217)
[error]     at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:415)
[error]     at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:364)
[error]     at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1119)
[error]     at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:71)
[error]     at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:267)
[error]     at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.prepareStatement(ConnectionHandle.java:820)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.SequenceIdGenerator.getMoreIds(SequenceIdGenerator.java:193)
[error]     ... 80 more
[info] x models.ModelTest.checkThatIndustriesExist
[info] 
[info] 
[info] Total for test models.ModelTest
[info] Finished in 2.028 seconds
[info] 1 tests, 1 failures, 0 errors
[error] Failed: : Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0, Skipped 0
[error] Failed tests:
[error]     models.ModelTest
[error] {file:/Users/martin/workspace/stackoverflow-10869508/}stackoverflow-10869508/test:test: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 03.06.2012 18:34:39
```

Comment: Thanks for testing code! Indeed I figured out that the evolutions haven't been applied (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

My ids look like this, and I don't get that error...

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long id;
```

Comment: This fixed it for me, the key is to add the @GeneratedValue annotation